# How to create a non rectangular window form in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any way of creating a non rectangular window form, such as circle or ellipse, in c# or .net?

 I saw these unique windows form shapes and they look really neat in several installations I've seen.

Also, is there any disadvantage in using this kind of design for non standard forms, such as sustainability, crashes, etc.?

Comment: how would this improve your app?

Comment: In a similar way a good design and graphics improves any app, I guess.

Comment: Good design would mandate not using circular windows.

Comment: @David Not necessarily. Maybe he wants to display a clock on the screen that should be circular and has no reason to take more space than it has to. Or maybe he wants to create a rectangular form with rounded corners (BTW in Windows XP all forms have rounded corners). Note that even the welcome screen of Visual Studio, while it is loading, has a very non-standard region.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Non Rectangular Winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664754/how-to-make-a-non-rectangular-winforms)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Form has Region property and you can assign there any shape that you create.
For example to create oval form you can use this code in `Form1_Load()` method of form:

```
 var path = new GraphicsPath();

 path.AddEllipse(0, 0, Width, Height);
 Region = new Region(path);
```

The risk is that when you create non-rectangular form and close, minimalize buttons are cut off by region then some of end-users could have problems with closing your application.

Comment: Note: both `GraphicsPath` and `Region` implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 4):

I worked with something like that. You can override the `OnPaint` method. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint( System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e )
{
    GraphicsPath wantedshape = new GraphicsPath();
    wantedshape.AddEllipse(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    this.Region = new Region(wantedshape);
}
```

And set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `FormBorderStyle.None`.

And there is no risk to use non standard forms. Just create an application that your users want. :)

Comment: isn't it suppose to be `wantedshape` instead of `shape` in `shape.AddEllipse(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);`? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be wanted shape, i want to make maybe more understandable code. I will change.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to make a window with no border and transparent background, and use an image to define the actual shape. Alternatively, you can make a window with a custom [`Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) that defines the shape.

Comment: Your suggestion is  the best solution, as when using Region property I see lots of issues on the form border.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx). You can make any Windows Forms control take any shape by setting its Region property. A region can be a rectange, an ellipse, a combination of multiple shapes, and you can even generate it from a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
objGP = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

objGP.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
Region = new Region(objGP);

var formGraphics  = CreateGraphics();
string drawString = DtDaysRemaining;
var drawFont  = new Font("Arial", 20);
var drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

float x = 20, y = 20;

var drawFormat = new StringFormat();
formGraphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, x, y, drawFormat);

drawFont.Dispose();
drawBrush.Dispose();
formGraphics.Dispose();
```