# InkEdit globally and not only inside my program

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge

I want to create a ruler like seen in drawing apps that works globally. I have found that I could create something like this with an [Inkedit Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/windows/desktop/tablet/inkedit-control-reference) or [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SimpleInk/cs/Scenario8.xaml.cs), but both only seem to work inside of the specific application.

Is there a way to make either of those work globally, and create a system-wide tool that can re-adjust the location of pen input? Would a .Net-type mousehook help in any way? If so, how would I catch only the pen that way if it is possible? Or in the worst case, can my ruler catch both?

I also took a look at input injection, and I can indeed inject the input caught in an UWP app to an unrelated application. There are issues with this too, however:

- In UWP, I seem not to be able to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445230/how-to-create-a-non-rectangular-window-form-in-c) working.
- In .NET, non-rectangular windows work, but I can't seem to make input injection work in .NET.

Comment: UWP apps run in sandbox. It's impossible.

Comment: @Bite Thanks, updated tags!