# Can't maximize The Form When I Used The Rounded Borders in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with rounded borders by codes below:

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
(
    int nLeftRect,     // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nTopRect,      // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nRightRect,    // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nBottomRect,   // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
    int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 30, 30));
}
```

But the problem is:When I Maximize the form, It doesn't maximize correctly.
It Maximizes like this:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZAxc.png)
Please Help Me...

Comment: And what happens if you try to resize the form? Hint: you may need to do something when form size is changed.

Comment: More likely you are doing custom drawing, then [Paint event/override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445286/1997232) might be appropriate.

Comment: You are not repainting the form on size changed you should look into overriding the `onPaint` method like @Sinatr said.

Comment: It is easy to see from the code snippet, note how you use the Width and Height properties.  They change, so you need the Resize event to do this correctly.  No need for rounded borders when the WindowState isn't Normal.

Comment: I know that i have to do something by maximizing but i don't know the codes @Sintar

Comment: Can you explain more?@HansPassant

Comment: I don't want rounded borders when the WindowsState isn't Normal too. I want to remove the rounds and just maximize to take all the screen. Can you help me in codes? @HansPassant

Comment: I can't imagine what code you need.  Maybe you don't know how to get the normal border back, set the Region property to null.

Answer (score 0):

I Found The Answer ...
I should clear the all borders that I set before like this:

```
private void btnMaximize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                btnMaximize.Image = Properties.Resources.maximize_Black;
                Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 30, 30));
            }
            else
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;;
                btnMaximize.Image = Properties.Resources.maximize_Black_copy;
                Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 0, 0));
            }
        }
```

Thanks For All Friends Wanted To Help Me.