# C# transparent form causes image to have ugly borders

Tags: c#, image, border, transparency

I have a transparent form in C# and on top of the form I have a splashscreen picturebox with an image. The form's backcolor is actually just Control gray. I also just set the form's transparencykey to Control gray as well. I used the tutorial here to make the form transparent: [How to design a cool semi transparent splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979232/how-to-design-a-cool-semi-transparent-splash-screen)

The image is stretched over the picturebox to make it fit nicely on all computer screen resolution. Here is the original image, notice that it has a transparent left side with squares which does not have any borders. 
[OriginalImageInPhotoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrETS.jpg)

However afterwards, the form has these ugly borders on the left side of the image that are the same color as the backcolor & transparencykey (in this case, Control gray). If I place the form over a black background, you can quite visibly see this. How can I get rid of this?
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xnUj.jpg)

So far, only remedies I have found is to either not have the image set to stretch in the picturebox (but that would cause it to appear different on every computer screen!) or perhaps theres another way to make a form transparent...

Comment: Can you post the code? There are a few things it could be, but without seeing the code it's impossible to tell which.

Comment: @Abion47 Theres pretty much no code yet. Just this.TransparencyKey = Color.Gray; and this.BackColor = Color.Gray inside the constructor of Form1.

Comment: In that case, my guess is that it's a combination of the Image scaling to a different size than its original size and the resulting aliasing causing parts of the Form under to be a slightly different color (thus making them no longer match the TransparencyKey).

Comment: Gray may not be the best choice since it is more likely to be in the good parts of your screen that, say, Fuchsia. It is best to get rid of all semi-tranparent pixels, imo, as the backcolor that shines through will always clash with some parts of the desktop..